# Trapezoidal Rule f(0) not defined

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have been asked to estimate $\int_0^1 x \log x dx $ with the trapezoidal rule.  But $f(0)$ is not defined.  How can I get round this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $x \log x \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.